# Can't Get document.getElementById("wp_mep_1").autoplay=false; to Execute after cookie is set

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I Know the cookie is executing because I have the alert popping up. If i place

document.getElementById("wp_mep_1").autoplay=false;

Outside of the if else statement then it will fire off and shut down the video. Any suggestions on what is wrong with my code. This is a nice piece of script for anybody that is trying to solve this problem with a video player that executes after visiting a page. Hope this helps someone besides me when I can get it fixed.

Thanks

Here's the code.

```js
<script>

function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
    var user=getCookie("username2");
    if (user != "") {
        alert("Welcome again " + user);
     document.getElementById("wp_mep_1").autoplay=false;
    } else {
       user = ("ACNEDominationVideo");
       if (user != "" && user != null) {
           setCookie("username2", user, 30);
       }
    }
}
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1><span style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 52px;"><strong><div class="su-heading su-heading-style-default su-heading-align-center" style="font-size:22px;margin-bottom:20px"><div class="su-heading-inner"><span style="color: #ff0000; font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 32px;"> <span data-icon="&#xe044;"></span> Acne Domination Will Show You The Way <span data-icon="&#xe044;"></span> </div></div></span></strong></span></h1>
<p style="text-align: center;"> <video id="wp_mep_1" src="http://acnedomination.101onlineorg.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/videos/test2.mp4"  width="740" height="360"  controls="controls" preload="none" autoplay="true" >





</body>
<body onload="checkCookie()">
</html>
```

Comment: When I try to run your snippet the Javascript console complains of a syntax error. You have `<script>` inside the `<script>` block.

Comment: SO Stack Snippets are sandboxed, so they're not allowed to set cookies.

Comment: It works for me at jsfiddle, it doesn't block cookies: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/7x51c2j7/

Comment: What in the world is with two body tags?

Answer (score 0):

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
    var user = getCookie("AcneDominationVid");
    if (user != "") {
    //alert ("welcome");
    var get = true;
            if (get == true){
            document.getElementById("wp_mep_1").autoplay=false;
            }
    } else {
        user = ("ACNEDominationVideo3");
        if (user != "" && user != null) {
            setCookie("AcneDominationVid", user, 30);
        }
    }
}
checkCookie();
```

This fixes it.